# iterate repetitive operation of columns of certain class

Tags: r, dplyr

Iterate a repetitive operation (simple arithmetic) over variables of a certain class and return the new values, with succinct code.

I have tried to code a for loop and use dplyr case_when to do an operation. The operation is to divide numeric columns by a particular numeric column and return new additional columns with the result of the operations. I have the following dummy data and code:

```
 Sp<-   c('ALF-01', 'AMB-01')
 norWT<-    c(4,    74.25)
 stateWT<-  c(4,    74.25)
 avWT<- c(1.1,  3.4)
 t<-data.frame(Sp, norWT, stateWT, avWT)
```

I want to divide the two numeric columns (norwt, stateWt) by avWT
tried the following for loop

```
output <- vector("double", ncol(t))  
for (i in seq_along(t)) {            
  output[[i]] <-(t, class =='numeric')[[i]]/avWT      
}
output
```

just returns error

the expected result should be something like:

```
    Sp1     norWT1  stateWT1 avWT1  norWT_avWT1     stateWT_avWT1
    ALF-01  4.00    4.00    1.1     3.636364        3.636364
    AMB-01  74.25   74.25   3.4     21.838235       21.838235
```

It would be great to see a for loop and `dplyr` (`mutate`/`case_when`) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` to divide specific columns

```
library(dplyr)

t %>% mutate_at(vars(norWT, stateWT),list(avWT1 = ~./avWT))

#     Sp norWT stateWT avWT norWT_avWT1 stateWT_avWT1
#1 ALF-01  4.00    4.00  1.1    3.636364      3.636364
#2 AMB-01 74.25   74.25  3.4   21.838235     21.838235
```

Using base R, you could do it directly as well.

```
cols <- c("norWT", "stateWT")
t[paste0(cols, "_avWT1")] <- t[cols]/t$avWT
```

Also `t` is a name of a function in R, so better to use some other name for dataframe.

---

If there are many more columns and we need to operate this only on numeric columns, we can use `mutate_if`

```
t %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(avWT1 = ~./avWT)) %>%
  select(-avWT_avWT1)
```

Comment: thanks. Would you be able to post a for loop example as well, just to get my head around it. Cheers

Comment: thanks again @ronak. In my real data situation it would be useful if I call the class numeric as there are a lot of variable columns in the dataframe. Cheers

Comment: You can find all the numeric column names with something like `colnames(t)[sapply(t, is.numeric)]` (you would have to exclude `avWT` somehow, since that's also a numeric column)

Comment: @Tom You could also use `mutate_if`, `t %>% mutate_if(is.numeric,list(avWT1 = ~./avWT))` but this would give you an extra column with `avWT` which you might want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` we can do

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c("norWT", "stateWT")
setDT(t)[,  paste0(nm1, "_avWT1") := lapply(.SD, `/`, avWT), .SDcols = nm1]
t
#        Sp norWT stateWT avWT norWT_avWT1 stateWT_avWT1
#1: ALF-01  4.00    4.00  1.1    3.636364      3.636364
#2: AMB-01 74.25   74.25  3.4   21.838235     21.838235
```